# I don't understand the Share facebook Button

Tags: facebook

I recently did a mini game that i added in "my application" in facebook.
I wanted to add a share/like button, but even if i follow the docs steps, i havn't found how to make a share/like button for my app.

i did the following code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'myappid',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=390850244392735";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

and added that :

but nothing happened... so i tryed that

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href=myweblink" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

That one worked but i have a like for the webpage and not the app... I searched for the app link to add into the `data-send` but there is nothing on the page...

Can someone help me pls? maybe is because is 4'o'clock but i really don't understand ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank">
 Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Reference here: 
[Facebook Docs share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/)